# Hiding UIAlertView hides Botton UITabBar also

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uitabbar, uialertviewdelegate

I stuck in a strange problem.

My app is not a `UITabBarController` application, while I added a `UITabBar` to `self.window`.

On appDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I added `UITabBar` like this:

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window)
     window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
    [[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:self.tabbar];
```

Adding directly as `subView` of `window`, `UITabBar` does not rotate with device, so I added it as above code.

When app launches, it shows a conditional `UIAlertView` like this screenshot and `UITabBar` also looks good here:

[image]

But when I click `YES` or `NO`, then `UITabBar` also goes hidden as `UIAlertView` 
[image]

Why it happens? I tried adding `UITabBar` on `UIAlertView` click but same issue. Issue does not come if `UITabBar` is added directly to `window` as `[self.window addsubview:self.tabbar];`
 Any help?

**(It has several reasons why it is not a `UITabBarController` app. I found adding `UITabBar` more useful as per my app's requirements.)**

Comment: You're doing nasty, hacky things you're not supposed to do (`[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:self.tabbar];`) and that's the price you're paying ;-) You need to find a different, clean way to add your tab bar to your view hierarchy. Also, `window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];` might give you something that's not your app's main window.

Comment: Then whats other option if I want to allow rotation of `UITabBar` along with `device`? 

Comment: Correctly implement a root view controller that allows for rotation. Maybe you should try to use a `UITabBarController` after all: don't try fight the system, try to understand it.

Comment: But if you'd like to continue your hacky way: you could experiment with something like this: subclass `UITabBar`, override `didMoveToWindow` and when `[self window]` is nil, re-add it to your window :-) Maybe you'll need to do it in the next runloop iteration, e.g. using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and a delay of 0 or `dispatch_after`.

Comment: The problem might be that you are adding the TabBar to the UIAlertView and not your window. The thing is, that when a UIAlertView is shown it will become the keyWindow! So if you are already showing the alertView and add a subview to the keyWindow, you are adding subviews to the alertView.